# Moving endpoint of freeform curve

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2010

How do you move the endpoint of a freeform curve?

This seems like it should be really simple but whenever I try with either the freeform tool or the pencil tool, it extends the curve rather than moving the endpoint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the spline tool, click and release on the endpoint to turn it purple (selected). THEN you can drag it to reposition it.  Sometimes Visio refuses to turn the endpoints purple, however you can still tell when the endpoint is draggable because the cursor turns into a drag cursor (crossed arrows) when directly over the endpoint.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks.  BTW, for anyone else interested, I wasn't sure what the Spline tool was.  It seems to be the Arc tool.  At least that's what works in Visio 2010 using Ex Umbris' method.

Comment: It works with either the arc or freeform tool, aka the spline or bezier tool.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried selecting the curve using the **Pointer tool**? That should display only the endpoints and allow you to move them.

Comment: Thanks.  Not quite what I was after as it operates on the whole shape (rotating it or stretching the whole shape, rather than just moving the end point).  However, I think I can use this in combination with the pencil tool to get the result I'm after.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem with not being able to move the endpoint, or other points, to adjust a freeform drawing in Visio 2010.  I tried the following, and it works.  Use the (straight) line tool to draw a short line bisecting the freeform area you want to move.  This short line will be your cutting line.  Select the short line and the freeform shape, and activate the Trim function (a shape operation found on the Developer tab).  Erase both segments of the cutting line.  The part of your freeform drawing that you want to move/adjust will now be a freeform segment that is separable from the rest of the drawing.  You can grab its endpoint and adjust/stretch/move it however you want.  You can use this method to separate any part of a freeform drawing to adjust it.  When finished, group the drawing together again to create a single freeform shape.

Comment: If you want to preserve the aspect ratio of the grouped freeform drawing, use the Join function on it first (another shape operation in the Developer tab).